# How to validate a username using external .txt files

Tags: python, validation, authentication, external

So recently I have been doing a coding project and I want to use an external file (*.txt file*) which contains all of the valid usernames. In this piece of code, I'm validating whether P1Username is valid. If the username is valid, it would proceed to later parts of the code. If the username is invalid (*not in the .txt file*), it would ask whether they want to be registered where the user can choose to register (*name added to .txt file*) or not register (*user referred to as Player 1*).
The problem is that this code allows all names to be enter as being valid and also does not output any of the print statements. Does anybody know what to do to fix this?

```
valid=False
username=open("username.txt","r")
lines=username.readlines()
P1Username=input("Enter your username Player 1: ")
for counter in range(len(lines)):
    if P1Username==str(lines[counter]):
        print("Valid username\nHello "+str(P1Username))
        valid=True
        break
    elif valid==False and counter<len(lines):
        next
    elif valid==False and counter>=len(lines):
        enter=""
        while enter!="yes" and enter!="no":
            enter=input("Would you like to register "+P1Username+"? (yes or no) ")
            if enter=="yes":
                username=("username.txt","a")
                username.write(P1Username)
                username.write("\n")
                print(P1Username+" is now a registered login\nHello "+P1Username)
                break
            elif enter=="no":
                P1Username="Player 1"
                print("You did not register the username\nI will refer to you as Player 1")
                break
            else:
                print("Enter yes or no")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that instead of doing a `for` loop iterating by index (like you are doing with the counter), to use a `for each` loop, like the following:

```
valid=False
usernames=open("username.txt","r")
P1Username=input("Enter your username Player 1: ")
for line in usernames.readlines():
    if P1Username in line: 
        valid = True

{go on with your code}
```

In your code you will bring the user to create his user as many times as names you have in the file.
With the code above, you separate the verification from the process afterwards.

I think this will simplify your code, allowing for quicker and easier fixes.

Comment: If you want to check if the string matching the given username is in the file you just need to use 'if username in line', you don't need to start dealing with every char.

Comment: If you still want to delete the newline character just add "line.strip('\n')"

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
if P1Username==str(lines[counter]):
    print("Valid username\nHello "+str(P1Username))
    valid=True
    break
```

will never be executed because `lines[counter]` has newline charecter '\n' at the end and user input does not. So even if the name is already in the text file the if condition will be evaluated to False (i.e. 'username' and 'username\n' are not the same.

This part

```
elif valid==False and counter>=len(lines):
    enter=""
    while enter!="yes" and enter!="no":
        enter=input("Would you like to register "+P1Username+"? (yes or no) ")
        if enter=="yes":
            username=("username.txt","a")
            username.write(P1Username)
            username.write("\n")
            print(P1Username+" is now a registered login\nHello "+P1Username)
            break
        elif enter=="no":
            P1Username="Player 1"
            print("You did not register the username\nI will refer to you as Player 1")
            break
        else:
            print("Enter yes or no")
```

will never be executed because in the for loop you use counter will take values from 0 to len(lines)-1, so `counter>=len(lines)` will never be True.

So I would something like

```
with open("username.txt","r") as f:
    usernames = [line.strip() for line in f]

player1 = input("Enter your username Player 1: ")
if player1 in usernames:
    print(f"Valid username\nHello {player1}")
else:
    while True:
        enter=input(f"Would you like to register {player1}? (yes or no) ").lower()
        if enter == "yes":
            with open("username.txt","a") as f:
                f.write(f'{player1}\n')
            print(f"{player1} is now a registered login\nHello {player1}")
            break
        elif enter == "no":
            player1="Player 1"
            print("You did not register the username\nI will refer to you as Player 1")
            break
        else:
            print("Enter yes or no")
```